# How to know which id has been clicked in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know that which button has been clicked in jquery. I have the html file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well " id="option_a">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well " id="option_b">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well " id="option_c">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well " id="option_d">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to know which option has been clicked?

Comment: and where's your js code?

Comment: Where are the buttons?

Comment: _"want to know that which button has been clicked in jquery"_ `button` element not appear at `html` at Question ?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal varun and guest, please upvote!

Comment: This question should be tagged with `html` too.

Comment: @learner Do you want solution or upvotes?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal It doesn't matter. But sometimes we don't rely on those questions, which are downvoted. So, if question is good, it should be upvoted, so that in future any one can take a help of it. I know after edit, it is a good question.

Comment: @learner _"want to know that which button has been clicked"_ What is `button` ?

Comment: It was just a typo. By the way thanks for downvotes. :D

Comment: @learner _"It was just a typo"_ What was "typo" ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are binding event with element with class "**well**"

You can add code like following

```
$(".well").click(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Comment: and are your sure to use this.id even if the OP want to get children id instead of clicked element?

Comment: Well, I understand the cross questioning, however, my objective was to explain the view point of how to extract id if the click event is binded to multiple elements.

Comment: @A.Wolff I can't get the conversation. Please explain

Comment: @A.Wolff - there is nothing wrong with that too. It will also work like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
$('div.well').click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

And here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k2Lhekpp/

There is `alert` instead of `console.log` and the `div` containers have red background color with width and height each 100px for better visualization of the clicks.